# Rebuilding Unique Index with uniqueidentifier in SQL Azure never succeeds

Tags: sql-server, index, azure-sql-database

We have a number of tables (~1M records) that have a column on them defined as: `[GlobalID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL` that gets auto-populated with `newid()`. We use this ID for synchronizing data across multiple systems, databases, file imports/exports, etc.

For this column, we have the following index created:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IxUx_XXXXXX_GlobalID] ON [dbo].[XXXXXX] 
(
    [GlobalID] ASC
)
```

As expected, this index gets fragmented pretty quickly so we have to be on the ball with keeping it rebuilt. However, this is where we have a problem. My maintenance script that goes through and rebuilds all indexes over x% fragmented with `ONLINE=ON` always hangs forever on these indexes. I've tried to let one run for over 3 hours without success when the database was mostly to completely idle. Just for kicks, I even put the DB into single user mode and nothing changed. I also tried with `ONLINE=OFF`, again with no change. However, I *am* able to simply drop/create the index and it completes within ~15 seconds!

Just to make sure there's nothing funny with my maintenance script, I've manually tried rebuilding these indexes with no success. The script I use is: `ALTER INDEX IxUx_XXXXXX_GlobalID ON [dbo].[XXXXXX] REBUILD WITH (ONLINE=ON)` and it seems like it will never succeed. Given that I can drop and recreate it in only 15 seconds, 3 hours is WAY more than plenty to see this succeed on an idle database.

For now, I've altered my maintenance script to filter out indexes with "GlobalID" in the name and then have a follow-up script that drops/creates these indexes. This gets us by until we start having naming variations on these types of columns (i.e. we need a uniqueidentifier for some other purpose).

Any idea why rebuilding such indexes would never finish within a reasonable amount of time? I see this happen across ~12 tables, all with essentially the same column/index on them.

Comment: Does the fragmentation on these indexes actually cause any *observable* performance problems? How long after the drop/create are they completely fragmented again (e.g. how much does the drop/create really buy you)? I suspect you are performing this maintenance to keep the fragmentation numbers low rather than in response to an actual performance issue.

Comment: (To be more specific, unless you are scanning this index very often, which shouldn't be the case, the fragmentation should be dismissible. Fragmentation won't have much effect on seeks at all, which is what a unique index should most often be facilitating IMHO.)

Comment: We query on this column quite a bit when bringing in outside data. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Well, what kind of query? Does the plan show index scans? Is the I/O (logical reads) way out of whack? Is the data for the index typically in memory anyway? Again, just because fragmentation on a particular index is high does not mean it's causing an actual problem you need to solve.

Comment: Also, I'm not trying to brush this off; this definitely sounds like a support ticket in the making, as this isn't how it should work. But for your particular scenario I'm just suggesting that perhaps you should be ignoring these indexes altogether or just dropping/re-creating them less frequently. If the latter accomplishes the same goal, I'd say go with that until Azure support tells you why the rebuild is not completing.

Comment: Honestly, I can't say if there are major performance problems or not with these indexes. I'm not aware of any perf issues with this, anways. Ultimately, I'm doing an 80/20 attempt at managing indexes. I'm a dev doing DBA work (and obviously, am not the best at it). Ultimately, we do have some indexes that cause very major problems to us if I don't keep them refreshed. Simply rebuilding all indexes that are fragmented has always served us well before. Do you have an alternative strategy for me to follow instead? We have ~450 tables so hand-picking what to rebuild is quite difficult.

Comment: Well you can certainly dynamically determine if an index has a uniqueidentifier column as a key, rather than rely on the name of the column.

Comment: I guess that is an idea. Toss that down as an answer and I'll give you a check mark and a smiley face! BTW, something else I just remembered is that when this thing churns, it seems to lock the entire table, even when performed with `ONLINE=ON`, which I also thought wasn't supposed to happen. Is that correct?

Comment: Are you saying you observe this symptom when using ONLINE=ON with the GUID indexes only, or all the time? If with the GUID indexes only, I suspect it has something to do with the fact that it never finishes, not anything to do with what ONLINE option you specified. (e.g. the locking problem is coming from elsewhere.)

Comment: It's just with these GUID indexes, not all others indexes.

Comment: Then I think that is a different symptom of the same problem (and not an indication that ONLINE=ON doesn't work). You should demonstrate this to Azure support - they can dig into this deeper than you can (since you only have access to certain DMVs and very little other diagnostic capabilities).

Comment: I'll see if I can create a new database to reproduce this without the complexities of our database muddying up the issues and will see what they have to say about this. Thanks for all of the help!!

Comment: Sure thing. Please update us here with anything official you hear back from them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion would be:

(a) talk to Azure support. This is not how it should be working AFAIK.

(b) when building your list of indexes to rebuild/reorganize, add a NOT EXISTS clause to the criteria to eliminate any indexes with GUIDs as the leading key column:

```
SELECT name, etc.
 FROM sys.indexes AS i
 INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats AS s
 ON ...
 WHERE ... criteria ...
 AND NOT EXISTS 
 (
   SELECT 1 FROM sys.index_columns AS ic
     INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
     ON ic.object_id = c.object_id
     AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
     AND ic.key_ordinal = 1 -- only leading column
     AND c.system_type_id = 36 -- uniqueidentifer
     WHERE ic.index_id = i.index_id
 );
```

(c) before deciding to manually deal with these columns, wait until they actually cause you a performance problem that you can demonstrate and undeniably identify the fragmentation of this index as the problem.

(d) or, just use the inverse query in (b) to perform manual drop/create all the time instead of dealing with the problem over and over.

Comment: I'm working on a script to combine B) and D) right now (I'd rather have them refreshed just in case they may cause problems for us at some point in the future). I'll also recreate this in a new database for your A) suggestion. Thank you! :-)